# weird results when calculating WP7 GPS speed

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, windows-phone-7-emulator

im trying to calculate speed by myself using Windows phone GPS Emulator by Cohen.

```
  void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
  {
    DateTime curTime       = DateTime.Now;
    double curDistance     = e.Position.Location.GetDistanceTo(lastKnownPosition);
    TimeSpan curTimeOffset = curTime - lastRecvTime;
    double curSpeed        = curDistance / curTimeOffset.TotalSeconds;
```

when LastKnownPosition represents last GeoCoordinate, same thing about the lastRecvTime.
problem here im getting unstable results regarding curSpeed. sometimes the speed is 10m/s and sometimes it jump to 20m/s.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like typical Windows time estimation: http://xkcd.com/612/

Comment: Are you sure you are 'walking' in a straight line?

Comment: the GPS emulator is configured to do only straight lines, so yes

Comment: How often is this function being called? You might need to use some kind of running average to account for volatility of the measurements. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Comment: Collin Hockey: according to what i've seen, every 0.041 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The GPS has limited accuracy. If you get 20 fixes per second and move - say 10m/s than the difference in position is about 0.5m between two fixes, which is usually (depending on hardware, line of sight to the satellites and number of satellites available to your GPS) below the accuracy of the GPS.

Try using a fix every few seconds or keep a queue (you can use a circular array to efficiently implement the queue) of fixes and use the average speed. I would suggest a combination of both.

Comment: so what you're basically saying is that i should accumulate for : lets say about 3 seconds backwards and then find average speed by :
Total Distance Passed / 3seconds ?

Comment: Basically yes, but use the time difference from the Location instances.

Comment: Stefan: how can i translate the e.Position.Timestamp to utc, and is it the correct variable for time?

Comment: The timestamp is the time when the GPS hardware obtained the fix. For calculating the differences in time between fixes the time zone does not matter.